DLT UDFs with modular code - INVALID_ARGUMENT No module named 'mymodule'
I am migrating a massive codebase to Pyspark on Azure Databricks,using DLT Pipelines. It is very important that code will be modular, that is I am looking to make use of UDFs for the timebeing that use modules and classes.
I am receiving the following error:
org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: [UDF_ERROR.PAYLOAD] Execution of function <lambda>(MYCOLUMN_NAME1531) 
2) failed - failed to set payload
== Error ==
INVALID_ARGUMENT: No module named 'mymodule'
== Stacktrace ==

With the following code (anonymized to create a minimum working example):
# demo.py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
import dlt 
import mymodule

demodata = mymodule.DemoData("EX")
helper = mymodule.Helper(demodata)

@dlt.table(name="DEMO")
def table():
    return (
spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles")
.option("cloudFiles.Format", "PARQUET")
.load("abfss://...")
.withColumn("DEMO", helper.transform(col("MYCOLUMN_NAME")))
)


# mymodule.py
from pyspark.sql.typos import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

class DemoData:
    def __init__(self, suffix)
        self.suffix = suffix

class Helper:
    def __init__(self, demoData):
        _suffix = demoData.suffix
        self.transform = udf(lambda _string: self.helper(_string, _suffix), StringType())

    @staticmethod
    def helper(string, suffix):
        return string + suffix

Can someone help me understand what is happening? I am thinking that the Spark Worker cannot see my module. Is this correct? How would I use UDFs with modular code? I understand that this might not be ideal, but I want to understand this technicality.

You need to add you module path into system path like below.
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('<module-path>'))

And this works for the data set queries as Python modules as mentioned in this documentation.
So, any python modules which returns dataframe can be used in notebook.
If you want to use dependencies in DLT pipeline you have to install it using below command
%pip install yourWheelFile.whl

and in your notebook code you must keep this command at the start of the notebook.
Refer more about this here.
and check this article on how to build wheel file.
If none of the above works then execute the file and use the function.
with open('/Workspace/<pathTomoduleFile>/modules/sample.py', 'r') as file:
    exec(file.read())

Then use your function like below.
demodata = DemoData("EX")
helper = Helper(demodata)


Thanks; however this did not help. Manually adding the path did not change anything. Moreover, I understood that the comment as saying this step is not needed if all importable items are on the same project.

Ok then it only works for the modules which return dataframe and table. Try executing the file?
